# My angular service returns undefined value

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have a service like this :

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  
myData = 'example'
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) {
    console.log(this.myData )
  }
 
        async use(locData: string): Promise<{}> {
    locData = locData ? locData : await this.storage.get('locData');
    
    return new Promise<{}> ( async (resolve) => {
      const Path = `assets/i18n/${locData || 'data'}.json`;
      locData = this.myData;
      await this.storage.set('locData', this.myData);
      this.http.get<{}>(Path).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
          return resolve(this.data);
        },
        () => {
          this.data = {};
          return resolve(this.data);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

And also have a component, a login form where I want to use this service:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { MyService } from '../../shared/services/myservice.service';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TranslatePipe } from '../../shared/translate/pipes/translate.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'inc-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  imgError = false;
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  myData: string;


  @Input() alertMessage: string;

  @Input() loginConfig: LoginConfig = {
    title: '',
    version: '',
    versionLink: ''
  };


  constructor(
    public storage: Storage,
    private myService: MyService,
    private alertController: AlertController,
    private translate: TranslatePipe
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    
    this.initLoginForm();    
    this.myService.use(this.myData);
    this.storage.remove('user');
    this.storage.remove('role');
    this.storage.get('isRememberMe').then((result) => {
      this.loginForm.controls.isRememberMe.setValue(result);
    });
  }
```

I also imported the module of my service in the login module, and my app.module.ts looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, AppRoutingModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), IonicStorageModule.forRoot(), AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), AngularFirestoreModule, AngularFireAuthModule,
    LoginPageModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    
  ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I don't enter MyService in the providers array, I don't get a good value either, and it's still undefined the value of my service and I don't know why. Anyone have any idea what the mistake might be?

Comment: The property `myData` returns as undefined?

Comment: my use function uses the myData variable, the function works well, it returns the correct value, but when I use the injected service in the login component like this: this.myService.use (this.myData);
then I look at its value with console.log (this.myService.use (this.myData);), it will be undefined

Comment: Please write the ’use’ function

Comment: I modify the code above